# Borel measure that is locally finite but not borel regular

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, borel-measures

I was wondering if there is an obvious example of a borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that is locally finite but not borel regular, i.e. if there exists $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that for all borel sets $B$ with $E\subset B$ we have $\mu(B)\neq\mu(E)$.

Comment: Your definition of regularity does not make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited. The definition of borel regularity in my notes goes as follows: for all $E\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists a borel set $B$, $E\subset B$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(B)$.